# Understanding 'Cascade constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths'

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, cascade

I have some tables setup in SQL Server to store the results of a Regression so that they can be retrieved later and used to make predictions on a different object.

Model is the top of the hierarchy which represents the entire Model. A Model as multiple Terms, and a single Dependent Variable. A Term represents a value that was used as an Independent Variable in the Regression. Terms are made up of multiple Variables. 99% of the time Terms have only one Variable, but it's setup to allow multiple to allow for things like Polynomial regression in the future, for example if you want to use Height^2 as a value then the Height Variable would be included twice in a single term. The Variable table is used to retrieve values from a specific object type. Here is how the relationships are setup:

[image]

**Relationship A** is a `ON DELETE CASCADE`. When I delete a Model I want all Terms deleted as well.

**Relationship B** is `ON DELETE RESTRICT`.

**Relationship C** is `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

**Relationship D** is `NO ACTION`, since VariableClass is a static table that will likely never be deleted from.

I want **Relationship B** to also `CASCADE`, so when a Term is deleted all the Variables go, too. When running a migration with it setup that way I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Variable_Term_TermId' on table 'Variable' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I understand what the message is saying, and looking at the diagram it looks like deleting a Term would delete Variables which could then trigger the deletion of Models, etc. However **Relationship C** is `SET NULL`, and the `DependentVariableId` column allows nulls, so if a Model's Dependent Variable is deleted it should simply set the column null, right?

I could leave it as is and handle deleting Terms with Variables in code, but it would be neater to just allow the cascading.

Comment: You diagram says C runs both ways. Is it 2 FKs? It cannot have Variables referencing Model because DependentVariableId is not PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL there. Although if it were & you had a FK in that direction then null DependentVariableId wouldn't help because the referenced table must have a value matching a non-null referencing table value but Variables VariblId is a PK hence non-null. Please confirm what you mean for C. PS *Tables* represent (business) relationships. FKs (though mistakenly called 'relationships') are constraints saying values one place appear as PK/UNIQUE-NOT-NULL elsewhere.